# Intercepting method calls in C# using Proxies

Tags: c#, .net, marshalling, aop

What I'm trying to do is to be able to intercept calls to an object's methods and properties for cross-cutting concerns. I'm using proxy-based AOP using `ContextBoundObject`.

However this doesn't work for recursive method calls, The first call against the target will be intercepted by the proxy and successfully invoked, allowing me to do cross-cut here. However subsequent method calls from within the first method will stay within the target class and are **not intercepted** by the proxy as if no marshaling occurs!

Is there any way I can make it work? (I'm trying to avoid third-party libraries like PostSharp, Unity or Spring.Net)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var t = new SimpleObject();
        t.TestMethod1();
    }
}


[Intercept]
class SimpleObject : ContextBoundObject
{
    public string TestMethod1()
    {
        return TestMethod2();
    }

    public string TestMethod2()
    {
        return "test";
    }
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class InterceptAttribute : ContextAttribute, IContributeObjectSink
{
    public InterceptAttribute()
        : base("Intercept")
    { }

    public override bool IsContextOK(Context ctx, IConstructionCallMessage ctorMsg)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public IMessageSink GetObjectSink(MarshalByRefObject obj, IMessageSink nextSink)
    {
        return new InterceptSink(nextSink);
    }
}


public class InterceptSink : IMessageSink
{
    public IMessageSink NextSink { get; private set; }

    public InterceptSink(IMessageSink nextSink)
    {
        this.NextSink = nextSink;
    }

    public IMessage SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)
    {
        IMethodCallMessage mcm = (msg as IMethodCallMessage);

        // { cross-cut here }

        IMessage rtnMsg = this.NextSink.SyncProcessMessage(msg);
        IMethodReturnMessage mrm = (rtnMsg as IMethodReturnMessage);

        // { cross-cut here }

        return mrm;
    }

    public IMessageCtrl AsyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg, IMessageSink replySink)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: curious why u r trying to avoid postsharp?

Comment: Not my concern, it's the company policy!

Comment: That's unfortunate, PostSharp would give you this pretty easily, even the free aspects that don't require a license

Comment: Has anyone found a solution to this, without using PostSharp? I am facing this problem now...

Comment: I ended up using `System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy` to create a proxy for an object at runtime. You can intercept method calls in the overridden `Invoke` method. It is not pure AOP but with a little workaround you might be able to mimic AOP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C# designers have never been in favor of AOP, there's no easy way to intercept method calls without using Proxies and Marshaling, which have their own drawbacks!
In case anyone wants to intercept method/property calls (eg. cross cutting concerns), I've found `RealProxy` to be of some help.

RealProxy From MSDN:

> A client that uses an object across any kind of a remoting boundary is
>   actually using a transparent proxy for the object. The transparent
>   proxy provides the illusion that the actual object resides in the
>   client's space. It achieves this by forwarding calls made on it to the
>   real object using the remoting infrastructure.

Note: A type being proxied using `RealProxy` must be either an *interface* or inherit from `MarshalByRefObject`.

Here's some implementation of `RealProxy` using a Factory Method to create a proxy of an object at runtime:

```
public abstract class RuntimeProxy
{
    public static readonly object Default = new object();

    public static Target Create<Target>(Target instance, RuntimeProxyInterceptor interceptor) where Target : class
    {
        return (Target)new InternalProxy<Target>(instance, interceptor).GetTransparentProxy();
    }

    public static Target Create<Target>(Target instance, Func<RuntimeProxyInvoker, object> factory) where Target : class
    {
        return (Target)new InternalProxy<Target>(instance, new InternalRuntimeProxyInterceptor(factory)).GetTransparentProxy();
    }


    class InternalProxy<Target> : RealProxy where Target : class
    {
        readonly object Instance;
        readonly RuntimeProxyInterceptor Interceptor;

        public InternalProxy(Target instance, RuntimeProxyInterceptor interceptor)
            : base(typeof(Target))
        {
            Instance = instance;
            Interceptor = interceptor;
        }

        public override IMessage Invoke(IMessage msg)
        {
            var methodCall = (IMethodCallMessage)msg;
            var method = (MethodInfo)methodCall.MethodBase;

            try
            {
                var result = Interceptor.Invoke(new InternalRuntimeProxyInterceptorInvoker(Instance, method, methodCall.InArgs));

                if (result == RuntimeProxy.Default)
                    result = method.ReturnType.IsPrimitive ? Activator.CreateInstance(method.ReturnType) : null;

                return new ReturnMessage(result, null, 0, methodCall.LogicalCallContext, methodCall);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (ex is TargetInvocationException && ex.InnerException != null)
                    return new ReturnMessage(ex.InnerException, msg as IMethodCallMessage);

                return new ReturnMessage(ex, msg as IMethodCallMessage);
            }
        }
    }

    class InternalRuntimeProxyInterceptor : RuntimeProxyInterceptor
    {
        readonly Func<RuntimeProxyInvoker, object> Factory;

        public InternalRuntimeProxyInterceptor(Func<RuntimeProxyInvoker, object> factory)
        {
            this.Factory = factory;
        }

        public override object Invoke(RuntimeProxyInvoker invoker)
        {
            return Factory(invoker);
        }
    }

    class InternalRuntimeProxyInterceptorInvoker : RuntimeProxyInvoker
    {
        public InternalRuntimeProxyInterceptorInvoker(object target, MethodInfo method, object[] args)
            : base(target, method, args)
        { }
    }
}

public abstract class RuntimeProxyInterceptor
{
    public virtual object Invoke(RuntimeProxyInvoker invoker)
    {
        return invoker.Invoke();
    }
}

public abstract class RuntimeProxyInvoker
{
    public readonly object Target;
    public readonly MethodInfo Method;
    public readonly ReadOnlyCollection<object> Arguments;

    public RuntimeProxyInvoker(object target, MethodInfo method, object[] args)
    {
        this.Target = target;
        this.Method = method;
        this.Arguments = new ReadOnlyCollection<object>(args);
    }

    public object Invoke()
    {
        return Invoke(this.Target);
    }

    public object Invoke(object target)
    {
        if (target == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("target");

        try
        {
            return this.Method.Invoke(target, this.Arguments.ToArray());
        }
        catch (TargetInvocationException ex)
        {
            throw ex.InnerException;
        }
    }
}
```

You can use the `RuntimeProxy` as a factory to create a proxy of an object and intercept all method/property calls and invoke the actual method.

Here's a sample:

```
class SomeClass : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public int Mul(int a, int b)
    {
        return a * b;
    }

    public void SetValue(int val)
    {
        this.Val = val;
    }

    public int Val { get; set; }
}
```

Use `RuntimeProxy` class to create a proxy for an instance of the `SomeClass` class and intercept the calls:

```
var test = new SomeClass();
var proxy = RuntimeProxy.Create(test, t =>
{
    // cross-cut here

    return t.Invoke();          // invoke the actual call
});

var res = proxy.Mul(3, 4);      // method with return value
proxy.SetValue(2);              // void method, setting some property
var val = proxy.Val;            // property access
```

You could use interface types in case you don't want to inherit from `MarshalByRefObject` class.