# C# Property "Template"

Tags: c#

I'm still a relative newcomer to C#, but I'm getting there. One thing I'm really enjoying is finding ways to optimise and refactor my code to be smaller / more efficient. Something I particularly enjoy is adjusting areas where I break the DRY rule. However, I'm struggling with something.

I have a bunch of properties, each of which performs the *same* task on `set`, using parameters that are pertinent to the property in question.

```
private int _money      { get; set; }
private int _reputation { get; set; }
private int _intel      { get; set; }

public int Money
{
    get => _money;
    set
    {
        _money = value;
        OnResourceUpdated?.Invoke(UIManager.S.textMoney, _money);
    }
}
public int Reputation
{
    get => _reputation;
    set
    {
        _reputation = value;
        OnResourceUpdated?.Invoke(UIManager.S.textReputation, _reputation);
    }
}
public int Intel
{
    get => _intel;
    set
    {
        _intel = value;
        OnResourceUpdated?.Invoke(UIManager.S.textIntel, _intel);
    }
}
```

What I'm wondering is whether or not it is possible to create a "template" of sorts that matches the pattern of the three properties, so that when I create my members for Money, Reputation and Intel here, I can pass the two parameter types for each - `UIManager.S.Text, int` - in a simpler fashion, and not have to repeat myself for each member.

I'm sure this will involve something to do with Generics, but in my travels I haven't yet found an answer I can clearly understand enough to appropriate to what I have here. I imagine this'll be a cakewalk and I've missed something obvious, but either way, any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: No, there's nothing like that in C#. I'd also note that you don't have private fields (in source code) - you have private automatically implemented properties. It would be more idiomatic for them to be fields; just remove the `{ get; set; }` part from each one. You could have fields of another type which could raise the event, but you'd still need your properties to have manual getters/setters.

Comment: Do you want the code to be generated (snippet), or do you want to store the properties differently?

Comment: Well, as often you *could* use reflection, but you *shouldn´t*. It´ll make your code harder to read and more error-prone, not *easier*. Concentrate yourself on your **real** problems. At some place you **have** to resolve what `Money`, `Reputation` and `Intel` means, so you will need some mapoping from a property name to the underlying field and its update-action.

Comment: I wonder if you consider re-modelling this using `INotifyPropertyChanged` and Fody? https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged

Comment: Your solution won't involve Generics, Generics would be suitable if you wanted same functionality on different data types. Now to your question, there 2 possibilities. You can buy and use postsharp, which is same as what @mjwills wrote. Or you can add attributes and intercept setter calls and invoke your own notification like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13659185/intercepting-method-calls-in-c-sharp-using-proxies?rq=1)

Comment: @CodeCaster I assume it'd be a snippet as these things will all do the same thing, more or less (at this time).

Comment: These seem like some great responses - thank you everyone. Just need to read through all the suggestions and try to understand everything you've said. Thanks so much, I can't believe how quickly you all replied.